# Is there an RSS feed for new/unanswered questions?

Tags: support

Is there an RSS feed for new/unanswered questions? I could not find any RSS feeds functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the SE sites support various feeds, but I don't think there is an exlicit link in the `<body>`.

The feed for the main site is: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/feeds

Tags also have feeds, eg https://drupal.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/7

For more information, you can read [What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519)

Comment: Thanks @MPD. I am super updated now!